# Where does the Valmiki Ramayana state that Lord Rama killed Ravana in the month of April/May?

Tags: ramayana, rama

Are there any verses in Valmiki Ramayana which say that Lord Rama killed Ravana in the months Of April/May and returned Ayodhya at the time of April/May only?

Comment: @keshav srinivisan I edited my question.

Comment: I can answer as per Skanda Purana.

Comment: @the destroyer you can answer it.

Comment: Valmiki Ramayana doesn't say explicitly say the month but by calculations from Kishkindha Kanda to Yuddha Kanda, we can come to a conclusion. So, I think you may not look into other Puranas. That comment by Destroyer was made before closing a question. It's now an obsolete comment